# Retrieve data from mysql database to create a new user

Tags: mysql, database, linux, bash, cron

So far I have made a user input webpage for users to register and it adds the data the user entered to a registered users database. That works.

what I then want to do is read the registered users table in the database, then run some tasks (bash script) based on that information but I don't know how to do this.

so far I've got:

```
$MYSQL -e "select username from registeredUsers"
```

which returns the data the users have entered, but im not sure how to pass this off to a script job.

Answer (score 0):

do it in script

```
$MYSQL -e "select username from registeredUsers" | sudo xargs -L 1 useradd
```

if user is already added, whole command would fail

you may want this

```
for u in `$MYSQL -e "select username from registeredUsers"`; do
     useradd $u
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store it to the array like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=(`mysql -e "SELECT username from registeredUsers" | xargs`)
echo ${#x[@]} # total number of user
echo ${x[1]} # first user since ${x[0]} is just the username table
```